# Builtin backup tool in LTS

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

I have been using the builtin backup tool for several months creating a automatic file every week.  Today I had a chance to use it to restore my files, stored in a USB stick just for backup that I can see it has 40gb of data on it but when I attempt to restore from it I get a message that "RESTORE FAILED, no backups to restore". I can see many deja-dup files but it does not restore my files of documents, pictures and music. It also created some strange files that I did not create,  "System volume information".  In restore I setup three files,  documents, music and pictures to be backed up.  Any help would be great.

Here are some example of the files that were saved that do not restore.
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/fred/System%20Volume%20Information/IndexerVolumeGuid
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/fred/deja-dup/duplicity-full.20181227T150524Z.manifest.gpg
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/fred/fred-XPS-8700/duplicity-full.20210106T212128Z.manifest.gpg

Thanks and I hope this helps

Comment: If you are properly pointing to the USB stick in the Deja-dup GUI, some details are needed. Please edit your question and include information about the files on your USB stick (a full directory listing is not needed, but show us some of the backup files)

Comment: always perform a restore test before needing it... that is a good practice professionals knows... because when its too late, its too late.

Comment: Organic Marble I think have added files that you requested. Thanks